# Manage a PowerBI report's permissions via API

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-api

Want to ask, maybe anyone knows API endpoints to manage report's permissions in PowerBI. Mostly interested in in way to grand direct access to a report via API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there isn't an end-point for this.
The nearest to it is [Groups - Add Group User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/groups/add-group-user) - where you can add a user to the Workspace.